# Is there documentation on XNA other than at MSDN?

Tags: xna, documentation

MSDN documentation of XNA seems to be incomplete and/or bad. Is there another resource available? And by documentation I mean of the library/framework itself, similar to what UNITY, SFML, or SDL all have available.

Comment: MSDN is the source for the official documentation, and while you can find tutorials and guides elsewhere you probably won't find a completely re-authored set of docs that are better than MSDN's. If you have a specific issue you can't figure out from the documentation, it may be better to post that as its own question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably won't find documentation available that's as good or better than MSDN, any specific questions / problems, search here and elsewhere online and if you're still not sure post a question.

That said, take a look at the [Education Catalog](https://web.archive.org/web/20150118050352/http://create.msdn.com:80/en-US/education/catalog) at the [App Hub](https://web.archive.org/web/20150211170813/http://create.msdn.com/en-US).
While not documentation, it provides many samples and lots of useful information.

Also, take a look at [Shawn Hargreves' blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/), there are many interesting posts relating to XNA.
There's also an [index of older, useful posts](https://shawnhargreaves.com/blogindex.html).

Comment: Thanks for the input, I think Josh had the answer I was looking for though.

Comment: I've updated my post to incorporate his comment.

Comment: +1 for Shawn Hargreves' blog - I would his posts are better documentation for XNA than the MSDN.  Unfortunately, they won't continue - he [recently moved off the XNA team](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2011/12/13/from-games-to-telephones.aspx) :(

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to George's great answer:

The DirectX documentation (on MSDN) contains many additional details that the XNA documentation does not provide. XNA is a wrapper over DirectX, after all.

Often you can easily guess (or check using PIX or perhaps ILSpy) the underlying DirectX methods that XNA is using, and then look up the documentation for those to find out what you need.